# I want to make video sites, but is it acceptable?

Tags: halal-haram, internet

I want to make a site where people can upload their own Anime series or even sell them, but is it Haram or Halal? But users will be greeted with a message, saying that "All the content you see is completely from imagination. Also, sexual content will face you a permanent ban (In short words, no Hentai).".

Also, I want to make a site for users to upload videos of their TF2, Minecraft, CoD, etc. gameplay, except GTA or any game with adult content.

Also, I want to sell virtual (as .vdi images based on Ubuntu) and physical game servers (based on Ubuntu). Would those be Halal or Haram?

Comment: Why do you think something of what you said above would be Haram, if you worry so?

Comment: @azam These usually have music, swearing, etc. involved in the videos, that's why. I plan to make money from the sites.

Comment: Just do your work....If you dont have bad thoughts nothing is gonna happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make a site where people can upload their own Anime series or even sell them, but is it Haram or Halal?

From my personal opinion it should be fine. I believe that drawings are fine until they actually mimic realistic people. More on [drawings](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=drawings).

Please keep in mind that if you do not have permission from the distributors or original authors, it might constitute stealing, which makes it forbidden. More on [piracy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=piracy).

> Also, I want to make a site for users to upload videos of their TF2, Minecraft, CoD, etc. gameplay, except GTA or any game with adult content.

That should be fine imo, just make sure it is not illegal, if so down the road you won't be able to monetize your website on a steady basis.

> Also, I want to sell virtual (as .vdi images based on Ubuntu) and physical game servers (based on Ubuntu).

That should be fine. However, beware of doing anything copyrighted as it can land you in trouble.

Comment: Is chibi Anime realistic or not?